# Bootstrap Navbar horizontal scroll

Tags: html, bootstrap-5, nav

I want a navbar to have a fixed-top but to remove any vertical scroll but I still want the ability to scroll horizontal.  In the code below the first div is fine, does not scroll at all (when resizing the browser window) but I want the second div to scroll horizontal when needed when resizing the window.

```
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 96px;height:30px">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align:middle;color:white; font-size:20px">Test Menu</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 9</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content" style="margin:4px">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year</p>
    </footer>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "the second div." To make something have no vertical scroll, you would wrap it with the following code.

```
<div style="width:auto; height:auto; overflow-y:clip">
    <!--Your code here-->
</div>
```

Then it will auto-size width and have horizontal scroll, if needed.

Comment: OK. I forgot to mention I want it to be fixed-top so when scrolling vertically the menu always stays at the top but it will scroll horizontal it moves. Does that make sense?

Comment: You'll probably want to edit your question to match what you meant. If you do, you can get more useful answers. In the original question, you said you wanted to "remove any vertical scroll."

If you're trying to make a sticky navbar, you can accomplish this easily in BS5 by including the `.sticky-top` class in your `<nav>` element.